# Accept only certain strings for a method in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a method in C# as you can see below

```
public static IEnumerable<User> QueryTheAD(string filter, string identifier) {
  if ( filter == "ANiceString" ) {
    // sexy code here
  }
}
```

which works well. However VS rightly shows that not all code path returns a value.

So is it therefore possible for me to specify that filter can only be one of these:

- "Tutor"
- "Year"
- "SecondName"

Comment: Thank you all ever so much for your help. Truly grateful!

_heads back to VS_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an enum or throw an `ArgumentException` if an invalid string was passed.

While enums only map to numbers, you could always have a mapping from the enum values to the strings in case you need string names for some reason.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you should use an enum instead of string? :)

```
enum filterEnum
{
   Tutor,
   Year,
   SecondName
}

public static IEnumerable<User> QueryTheAD(filterEnum filter, string identifier)
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: An `enum` does not prevent values without a name being passed to a method. So while an `enum` might indeed be more appropriate, it does not solve the problem per-se.

Comment: of course, but it works. Another solution would be to use custom types or something...

Comment: Never heard of enums.
I've only really just got into writing proper applications using C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No this type of compile time restriction isn't allowed.  The implementation of the method must handle all `string` values.  If one doesn't fit the contract of the method then you should throw an exception

Answer (score 3):

Normal behavior for invalid arguments is to throw ArgumentException.

Answer (score 2):

How about simple `switch`?

```
public static IEnumerable<User> QueryTheAD(string filter, string identifier) {
    switch (filter)
    {
        case "Tutor":
            //code here  
            break;

        case "Year":
            //code here  
            break;

        case "SecondName":
            //code here  
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("filter", "Unacceptable value of filter");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering what the other option was instead of multiple `if` statements Thanks Andrei!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends what the behavior is when `filter` is **not** one of those three strings.

If one of those is required you should either throw an ArgumentException:

```
public static IEnumerable<User> QueryTheAD(string filter, string identifier) 
{
    if(filter != "Tutor" || filter != "Year" || filter != "SecondName") throw new ArgumentException ("filter");

    // sexy code here
}
```

or use an `enum` to require one of the required values:

```
public enum LegalValues { Tutor = 1, Year = 2, SecondName = 3 }

public static IEnumerable<User> QueryTheAD(LegalValues filter, string identifier)
{
     // sexy code here
}
```